# Ubuntu trusty 14.04.2 LTS, error when install mariadb-server

Tags: apt, mariadb

I have this ubuntu :

> DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
>
> DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
>
> DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
>
> DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
>
> NAME="Ubuntu"
>
> VERSION="14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
>
> ID=ubuntu
>
> ID_LIKE=debian
>
> PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
>
> VERSION_ID="14.04"

I want install maria-db. I found this link : https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=cnrs&distro=Ubuntu&version=10.1&distro_release=trusty--ubuntu_trusty

So, from my shell with the root user, I executed :

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386,ppc64el] http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main'
sudo apt-get update
```

All seems ok. But, when I execute this final command :

```
apt-get install mariadb-server
```

I get this error :

```
apt-get install mariadb-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.1 (= 10.1.19+maria-1~trusty) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't understand where is my mistake :/

I tried :

```
apt-get install -f mariadb-server
```

or

```
apt-get upgrade && apt-get update && apt-get install mariadb-server
```

But there is always the same error!

If this can help...

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

shows :

```
deb http://eu-central-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://eu-central-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://eu-central-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main

deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe

deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe

deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

deb http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu trusty main

deb-src http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu trusty main

deb [arch=ppc64el,i386,amd64] http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main

deb-src [arch=ppc64el,i386,amd64] http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main
```

This is my (initial system autosave ?) source.list.save file (in /etc/apt) :

```
deb http://eu-central-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://eu-central-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://eu-central-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main

deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe

deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe

deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

deb http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu trusty main
```

deb-src http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu trusty main

Thanks you for any help !

Comment: There is a mix of Precise and Trusty repositories in the sources.list.

Comment: Then I must remove all Precise sources ?

Comment: @Mikewhatever, I added in my main post the content of the source.list.save.